# How to prevent @StateObject from being initialized twice in navigationDestination?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to create Feature Oriented App. i.e. Feature1, Feature2.

My expected result:

1. `ContentView` navigate to `Feature1View`:

   1. initialize `Feature1ViewModel` once
   2. navigate to `Feature1_1View`:

      1. initialize `Feature1_1ViewModel` once.

The problem:

1. `ContentView` navigate to `Feature1View`:

   1. initialize `Feature1ViewModel` twice and deinit once.
   2. navigate to `Feature1_1View`:

      1. initialize `Feature1_1ViewModel` once.

What I've tried:

1. use `static var shared`. The problem: How to detect the app have exit Feature1 (`.onDisappear()` is triggered when navigating from Feature1View to Feature1_1View)

```swift
class Feature1ViewModelManager {
    static var shared: Feature1ViewModel! {
        get {
            if sharedClosure == nil {
                sharedClosure = Feature1ViewModel()
            }
            
            return sharedClosure
        }
        set {
            sharedClosure = newValue
        }
    }
    
    private static var sharedClosure: Feature1ViewModel!
}
```

2. use the `if else statement` instead of using `NavigationStack` in `ContentView`. The problem is that I can't navigate back from `Feature1View` to `ContentView`

Feature1View.swift

```swift
enum Feature1ViewRoute {
    case Feature1_1
}


class Feature1ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    
    @Published var departure: Station?
    
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}

struct Feature1View: View {
    @StateObject private var feature1ViewModel: Feature1ViewModel
    
    init(feature1ViewModel: Feature1ViewModel = Feature1ViewModel()) {
        self._feature1ViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: feature1ViewModel)
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature1")
            Text("departure \(feature1ViewModel.departure?.name ?? "")")
            Button {
                feature1ViewModel.departure = Station(name: "Lebak Bulus Grab")
            } label: {
                Text("set departure")
            }
            NavigationLink(value: Feature1ViewRoute.Feature1_1) {
                Text("Go to Feature1_1")
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Feature1ViewRoute.self) { route in
            switch route {
            case .Feature1_1:
                Feature1_1View()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Feature1_1View.swift

```
enum Feature1_1ViewRoute {
    case Feature1_1_1
}


class Feature1_1ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}

struct Feature1_1View: View {
    @StateObject private var feature1_1ViewModel: Feature1_1ViewModel = Feature1_1ViewModel()
    
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature1_1View")
            
            NavigationLink(value: Feature1_1ViewRoute.Feature1_1_1) {
                Text("Go to Feature1_1_1")
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Feature1_1ViewRoute.self) { route in
            Feature1_1_1View()
        }
    }
}
```

Feature1_1_1View.swift

```
class Feature1_1_1ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}


struct Feature1_1_1View: View {
    @StateObject private var feature1_1_1ViewModel: Feature1_1_1ViewModel = Feature1_1_1ViewModel()
    
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature1_1_1View")
        }
    }
}
```